# find columns present in vector and replace values that equal 1

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I have a binary data set which looks like

```
     a    b    c   d
 r1  1    1    0   0
 r2  0    1    1   0
 r3  1    0    0   1
```

And a vector

```
 V <- c("a", "c")
```

I want to a command to search colnames and change values in these columns. for example change 1 to A. So the output would be:

```
     a    b    c   d
 r1  A    1    0   0
 r2  0    1    A   0
 r3  A    0    0   1
```

Comment: Please, note that this might be changing the type of data as well. If the columns were of type numeric or integer before the replacement the whole columns `a` and `c` will be of type character after replacement. Even the digits 0 and 1 although this cannot be judged from the print out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a vectorized way to do it,

```
df[names(df) %in% V] <- replace(df[names(df) %in% V], df[names(df) %in% V] == 1, 'A')

#or avoid calling the %in% part 3 times by assigning it, i.e.

i1 <- names(df) %in% V
df[i1] <- replace(df[i1], df[i1] == 1, 'A')

#or a more simplified syntax, compliments of @Cath,

df[, V][df[, V]==1] <- "A"
```

which gives,

> ```
>    a b c d
> r1 A 1 0 0
> r2 0 1 A 0
> r3 A 0 0 1
> ```

Comment: @Cath ahh...that's the syntax. My very first try - which fails -  was `df[names(df) %in% V][df == 1] <- 'A'` :p

Comment: well V are the names so no need for `%in%` (+ a bit of well-used code-golfing can never be bad ;-p )

Comment: Could not agree more! ;) - From now on Thursday is the "Overthinking stuff" day :p

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

V <- c("a", "c") 
df %>% 
  mutate_at(V, ~replace(.x, .x == 1, 'A'))

#    a b c d
# r1 A 1 0 0
# r2 0 1 A 0
# r3 A 0 0 1
```

`mutate_at` takes a a data.frame and a vector of column names and applys the specified function to each of the columns.

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 0L, 1L), b = c(1L, 1L, 0L), 
                     c = c(0L, 1L, 0L), d = c(0L, 0L, 1L)), 
                .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c("r1", "r2", "r3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If left hand side (LHS) and right hand side (RHS) or of the same type, then `data.table` can be used to update only the selected "cells" *in place*, i.e., without copying the whole column:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
for (s in V) df[get(s) == 1L, (s) := 99L]  # replacement value is of type integer
df[]
```

> ```
>     a b  c d
> 1: 99 1  0 0
> 2:  0 1 99 0
> 3: 99 0  0 1
> ```

To verify that only selected rows in each column are updated, we can check the addresses of each column before and after the update using:

```
df[, lapply(.SD, address), .SDcols = V]
```

(In addition, the verbose mode can be switched on by `options(datatable.verbose = TRUE)`.)

---

In case LHS and RHS are of different type, a type conversion is required anyway. Therefore, the whole column needs to be replaced:

```
df[, (V) := lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, x == 1L, "A")), .SDcols = V]
df
```

> ```
>    a b c d
> 1: A 1 0 0
> 2: 0 1 A 0
> 3: A 0 0 1
> ```

Using `address()` shows that each of the affected columns has been copied. But only the affected columns are copied, the other columns haven't been touched. This is different to the other answers posted so far where the whole data frame is copied.